# Изменения группы и пользователя

Tags: linux, ssh, chown

Как изменить группу и пользователя для папки, всех подпапок и файлов в SSH?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду просто группу и пользователя у папок ? тогда `chown  user.group -R dir` но причем тут ssh не понимаю

Comment: @Mike, *причем тут ssh* — многие начинающие пользователи не знают, что *secure shell (ssh)* — это всего лишь защищённый *remote shell (rsh)*, который, в свою очередь, является лишь средством для запуска *shell-а (оболочки)* на другом компьютере. и думают, видимо, что это какой-то **особый** режим/среда/регламент.

Answer (score 2):

согласно стандарту posix, [программа `chown`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chown.html) должна поддерживать опцию `-R`:

> -R
>       Recursively change file user and group IDs. For each file operand that names a directory, chown shall change the user ID (and group ID, if specified) of the directory and all files in the file hierarchy below it.

мой вольный перевод:

> -R
>   рекурсивно изменяет идентификаторы пользователя и группы у файлов. для каждого файлового операнда, обозначающего каталог, программа `chown` должна изменять идентификатор пользователя (и группы, если задан) для указанного каталога и для всех файлов (и каталогов), располагающихся в иерархии ниже него.

---

пример:

```
$ chown -R пользователь:группа путь/к/каталогу
```